# How to check mongoDB updateOne execution time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, execution-time, mongodb-compass, mongodb-explain

I have been using `.explain("executionStats")` to find the execution time for a get-call like below in mongoDB compass console sh:

```
db.getCollection('Employee').find({"value.attendence":{$elemMatch:{"$lt":"2023-03-11T08:49:00Z","$gt":"2023-03-11T08:51:00Z"}}}).explain("executionStats")
```

This works fine.

However now I want to see the update timings and not finding a proper query. I have some various size docs to be inserted into mongo and see what is the time being taken. Tried like below no luck.

```
db.getCollection('Test').updateOne({
    "fid": "9999"
}, {
    "$set": {
        "fid": "9999",
        "origin":"SKD"
    }
},
{"upsert": true},
{"$explain": 1})
```

Above giving no details.

---

```
db.getCollection('Test').explain().updateOne({
    "fid": "9999"
}, {
    "$set": {
        "fid": "9999",
        "origin":"SKD"
    }
},
{"upsert": true})
```

Above gives error!

DB details:

[image]

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     explain: {
        update: "Test",
        updates: [
           {
               q: { "fid": "1111" },
               u: { "fid": "1111", "origin": "SKD" },
               upsert: true
           }
        ]
     }
   }
)
```

I tried the above based on the answer, it did not insert on new record or update existing. Results:

```
  {
  queryPlanner: {
    plannerVersion: 1,
    namespace: 'sampledb.Test',
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: { fid: [Object] },
    winningPlan: { stage: 'UPDATE', inputStage: [Object] },
    rejectedPlans: []
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 0,
    executionTimeMillis: 10,
    totalKeysExamined: 0,
    totalDocsExamined: 3,
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'UPDATE',
      nReturned: 0,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 9,
      works: 6,
      advanced: 0,
      needTime: 5,
      needYield: 0,
      saveState: 0,
      restoreState: 0,
      isEOF: 1,
      invalidates: 0,
      nMatched: 0,
      nWouldModify: 0,
      nInvalidateSkips: 0,
      wouldInsert: true,
      fastmodinsert: false,
      inputStage: [Object]
    },
    allPlansExecution: []
  },
  serverInfo: {
    host: 'middleware-mongodb-86dbd85bcc-tcmx9',
    port: 27017,
    version: '4.0.14',
    gitVersion: '1622021384533dade8b3c89ed3ecd80e1142c132'
  },
  ok: 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/), MongoDB `explain` function returns stats only on one update function, which is `findAndModify`, you should use that to measure the execution time of your updates.

[FindAndModify](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#definition) method MongoDB.

There is one catch in using the `explain` function though, whenever you use `explain` the write operations, won't apply the changes to the database. So, it would be better if you turn on the profiling using `db.setProfilingLevel()` function. It will start logging your query details in the `system.profile` collection. You can then query this collection for query execution details.

[Query Profiling in MongoDB.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/)

Comment: Where to put `explain` in `findAndModify` above doc doesnt provide examples

Comment: It would be something like this db.collection.explain().findAndModify() @Jet

Comment: Somehow this did not update the data in db also did not show execution time taken, something with version ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$explain` with `runCommand`:

```
let result = db.runCommand(
   {
     explain: {
        update: "products",
        updates: [
           {
               q: { fid: 999 },
               u: {    "$set": {        "fid": "9999",        "origin":"SKD"    }},
               upsert: true
           }
        ]
     },
     verbosity: "allPlansExecution"
   }
)
// print results
result["executionStats"]["executionStages"]
```

see for [details](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.6/reference/command/explain/)

Comment: I dont see this is working either insert or update . Gives this messages in stats: `wouldInsert: false,
      fastmodinsert: false,`

Comment: It doesn't seem true, it prints results in my case with either `nWouldUpsert` or `nWouldModify` filled. Make sure that you run it not on admin db

Comment: Somehow this did not update the data in db also did not show execution time taken, something with version ?

Comment: It's by design and It doesn't update data based on the doc: `operations that would be performed, but does not apply the modifications to the database.`

Comment: you mean the data matching query inside `q` will only be updated ? Just added this info in question @dododo

Comment: Nothing will happen with collection data after this query. This command only emulate running command, but not actually apply changes

Comment: I see that on an empty collection, the output is different, make sure that there is at least one record in collection

Comment: ok, this means `db.runCommand()` is just a dry run without actually applying changes ? This will give the execution time like actual update made without using `db.runCommand()` ? This can just be used to see the _executionStats_ which are same as actual execution but not to make the actual changes ? @dododo

Comment: almost, but changes are not applied because `explain` command not `db.runCommand` . `db.runCommand` simply run whatever is provided for him

Comment: to clarify above: .. because the explain command is provided, not because it's running via db.runCommand