# How to use explain() in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In below code when ever I am trying to use ecplain() getting this error,"MongoInvalidArgumentError: Option "explain" cannot be used on an aggregate call with writeConcern".But why where I am doing wrong?

```
    const result1 = await this.qcInspectionModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            startDateQuery,
            endDateQuery,
            statusQuery,
            businessUnitFilterQuery,
            { isDeleted: false },
            { isSLCMQcInspection: true },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'mastercommodities',
          localField: 'commodityId',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                name: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'commodityData',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$commodityData',
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'commodityvariants',
          localField: 'commodityVariantId',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                name: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'commodityVariantData',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$commodityVariantData',
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'businessunits',
          localField: 'businessUnitId',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'businesses',
                localField: 'businessId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'businessClientName',
              },
            },
            {
              $unwind: '$businessClientName',
            },
            {
              $project: {
                name: 1,
                businessClientName: '$businessClientName.displayName',
              },
            },
          ],
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'businessUnitData',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$businessUnitData',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'createdBy',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'userData',
          pipeline: [
            {
              $project: {
                firstName: 1,
                lastName: 1,
                _id: 0,
                name: { $concat: ['$firstName', ' ', '$lastName'] },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$userData',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            commoditySearchQuery,
            variantSearchQuery,
            generalSearchQuery,
            cidNumberSearchQuery,
            lotNoSearchQuery
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          createdAt:
            filters.sortOrder && filters.sortOrder != SortOrder.Ascending
              ? SortOrder.Descending
              : SortOrder.Ascending,
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          status: 1,
          commodityData: 1,
          commodityDetail: 1,
          commodityVariantData: 1,
          createdAt: 1,
          qcId: 1,
          sampleName: 1,
          businessUnitData: 1,
          userData: 1,
          location: 1,
          middlewareStatus: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $facet: {
          records: [
            { $skip: (filters.pageNumber - 1) * filters.count },
            { $limit: filters.count * 1 },
          ],
          total: [{ $count: 'count' }],
        },
      }
    ]).explain();
```

Comment: do not use any language other than english

Comment: `cannot be used on an aggregate call with writeConcern"` - when you call operation with explain, the server takes all steps except actual writing (so effectively no real operation will be called). So `writeConcern` logic won't be called in any case and can be simply temporary removed

Comment: I have provided all my code,please find out and tell me where writeConcern logic is present in my code @dododo

Comment: it's configured on a higher level like in mongoClient

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {...}
   ], 
   { explain: true }
)
```

or

```
db.collection.explain().aggregate([
   {...}
])
```

Note, instead simple `{ explain: true }` you can also use `{ explain: 'executionStats' }` or `{ explain: 'allPlansExecution' }` to get more information.

Comment: for  2nd case getting  ,    Property 'explain' does not exist on type 'Model<QcInspectionDocument, {}, {}, {}>'.

4709     const result = await this.qcInspectionModel.explain().aggregate([                                              ,and for 1st case that same error  "MongoInvalidArgumentError: Option "explain" ".

Comment: Are you sure? Have a careful look where the brackets are. Try to run it in the mongo shell `mongosh`, maybe it is not implemented in node.js driver.

Comment: in mongo shell it is working fine like this,  db.qcInspectionModel.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: "mastercommodities", localField: "commodityId", pipeline: [{ $project: { name: 1 } }], foreignField: "_id", as: "commodityData" } }, { $unwind: "$commodityData" }], { explain: "executionStats" });             ,                       But it is not working in my project why?

Comment: As written, most likely not implemented in node.js. But I guess, you need it only for development but not in your application.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, the answer is correct, but there is one more way to write explain (for any operation and independent with shell syntax) via `runcommand`. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75789922/9492730.